# Struct Factories in Solidity

Tags: design-patterns, struct, solidity, factory-pattern, separation-of-concerns

So I am working on a DApp in Solidity and would like to make use of Separation of Concerns. I have a Contract that adds and removes Users. My Users are of type Struct. So I thought I would write another contract, a UserFactory Contract utilising the Factory Design Pattern and separating the concerns since a UserManager should not be responsible for creating Users. Unfortunately I am unable to return Structs from my Factory Contract unless I enable ABIEncoderV2, but since this is an experimental feature it won't work in production. It seems that for Solidity I need to find a different approach to solve this design problem. Is there a go to approach for Solidity? Any help would be gladly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a tuple of user properties instead:

```
mapping(uint -> User)
type User struct {
   string name;
   string address;
   uint age;
}
function getUser(uint key) public constant returns(string,address, uint) {
     return (users[key].name, users[key].address, users[key].age;
}
```

But I believe that it's safe to use ABIEncoderV2 . [Here](https://readthedocs.org/projects/solidity/downloads/pdf/develop/) is reference to official documentation

> ABIEncoderV2
> The new ABI encoder is able to encode and decode arbitrarily nested arrays and structs. It might produce less optimal
> code and has not received as much testing as the old encoder, but is considered non-experimental as of Solidity
> 0.6.0. You still have to explicitly activate it using pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2; - we kept the
> same pragma, even though it is not considered experimental anymore